# react limits the number of renders

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

in react I am displaying products I.E.

{renderPosts.map((item, index) => (
                ...

now, in each product, there is a button to delete that product, inside a button I have onclick that calls sweetAlert to delete particular product:

```
<Button
  color="danger"
  simple
  justIcon
  onClick={warningWithConfirmMessage}
 >
```

Everything works fine like that... but if I want to pass ID of the product that has to be deleted...

```
<Button
  color="danger"
  simple
  justIcon
  onClick={warningWithConfirmMessage(item.postId)}
 >
```

Now I am having error:

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

How I can pass anything to function... anybody

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `onClick={() => warningWithConfirmMessage(item.postId)}` - right now it's calling `warningWithConfirmMessage` every time it renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `onClick` handler you're passing is calling the `warningWithConfirmMessage` every time it renders. To pass the function as a handler function instead of calling it, use:

```
onClick={() => warningWithConfirmMessage(item.postId)}
```